# Best model for processing rss feeds

Tags: performance, node.js, mongodb, data-structures, rss

I am creating a podcast website and I was wondering what would be the best way to keep a database up to date within 15 mins with the podcast rss feeds.

Currently I parse a feed on request and store in redis cache for 15 mins. But I would prefer to keep a database with all the data (feeds and all episodes).

Would it be better to bake the data by constantly hitting all feeds every 15 mins on a processing server or to process the feeds when requested?

If I were to update rss feed when requested I would have to:

check database -> check if 15 mins old -> done || parse feed -> check for neew feeds -> done || add to database -> done

where done = send data to user.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a way to do it. There are protocols like [PubSubHubbub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) which can help you avoid polling "dumbly" every 15 minutes... You could also use [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) and just wait for us to send you the data we find in finds.

Comment: Does every podcast have to publish through superfeedr? I need a method that will work for all RSS feeds.

Comment: No, of course not, but we will do the polling/fetching for all the other feeds on your behalf :) We do that at scale since 2009

Comment: Cool, sounds good to me as long as it doesn't get too expensive with about 5000+ podcast feeds. I'll try it out.

Comment: If you have *any* concern about our pricing, please email me :) julien@superfeedr.com we will make sure this is not a road block.